# Combining object destructuring with flow-typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, static-typing, flow-typed

I just added [Flow](https://flow.org/en/) to my Create-React-App project, and while converting some of my calculation code to flow-typed, I encountered this error with a destructured "object as params"

Original sig:

```
calcWeightOnConveyor({ tonsPerHour, conveyorLength, conveyorSpeed })
```

After flow-type:

```
calcWeightOnConveyor({ tonsPerHour: number, conveyorLength: number, conveyorSpeed: number }): number
```

And the error:

```
$ flow
Error: src/utils/vortex/calculate.js:31
 31: export function calcWeightOnConveyor({ tonsPerHour: number, conveyorLength: number, conveyorSpeed: number }) {
                                                                                 ^^^^^^ Strict mode function may not have duplicate parameter names
```

Is there a way to use flow with object destructuring in this way or should I redesign these function APIs?

Comment: When you use colons in destructuring, the right side of the colon is actually creating a new variable. You are creating two variables named "number". Check out the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

Comment: Flow type collides with ES6 here.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/235

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally the pattern I follow, especially for functional components props is as follows:

```
type Props = {
  prop: Type,
};

const Component = ({
  prop,
}: Props) => ();
```

Comment: github link is 404 btw

Comment: oops :| removed since I think we have that repo private for now.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do so by annotating the entire object like the following:

```
calcWeightOnConveyor({
  tonsPerHour,
  conveyorLength,
  conveyorSpeed
}: {
  tonsPerHour:number,
  conveyorLength:number,
  conveyorSpeed:number
}):number
```

Comment: Probably the best answer until flow/ts address this with either `as` or paren-style { (tonsPerHour:number) } as referenced in @jonas-w comments above.